# AngualrJS Undefined or Null Reference When Accessing $rootSope in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS latest release candidate:

I am putting a javascript object - called say **stuff** into the $rootScope from the module's run function, which I believe is supposed to block.  This is the code:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'API'])
    .run(function ($rootScope, API) {
        $rootScope.stuff = null;

        // call the API
        API.getStuff()
            .success(function(data){
                $rootScope.stuff = data;
            })
            .error(function(data){
                $rootScope.stuff = null;
            });

    });
```

Now, when I attempt to access the **stuff** property of $rootScope from my controller, I am getting an 'undefined or null reference' error on **stuff**.  Code looks like this:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('indexController',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, otherAPI) {
        var
            stuff = $rootScope.stuff;

        // call the other API
        otherAPI.getDifferentStuff(stuff.property)
            .success(function(data){
                    $scope.differentStuff = data;
            })
            .error(function(data){
                        // do some error handling stuff here
            });
    });
```

I know the api call in the run function is succeeding, and it is assigning a value to stuff in the $rootScope.  Can anyone see anything obvious wrong with my code here?

Thanks for any help!

Rich

Comment: Why don't you just make the call in the controller? Throwing stuff into the rootscope is bad practice. If you want it accessible in more than one controller, create a service and inject it into each controller.

Comment: Zack, can you give me a good example of something that is accepted practice insofar as the use of $rootScope?  It seemed like the place to put global information that is needed by all controllers, since their scopes inherit from $rootScope.  Why would one go to the trouble of creating a service just as a container for a few data items?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `API.getStuff` an asynchronous api call (it looks like it). In that case most likely your controller is getting initialized before the asynchronous call has returned, so $rootScope.stuff is still equal to null. If you wait until the call succeeds, then you will have your data.

Comment: Thanks,  I believe you are correct about what is happening.  Apparently the run function does not block until all work contained is completed.